# Sharepoint permissions regarding One Drive

Tags: sharepoint-online, development, csom, onedrive-for-business

I am creating an application which makes folders for users and sharing it to them, in a main **OneDrive account**. Seems like the **permission** are not the same or some how being overridden by OneDrive permission.

**For Example :**

**First Scenario Details:** Visual Studio Folder - This Folder is created by my MVC application. Permissions are set and this folder is created.

This folder is created to a given user and permission are being set. However In this scenario the intended user *IS NOT* able to see this shared folder in his OneDrive under his **“Shared With Me”** section.

**Second Scenario Details:** GUI Folder – This Folder is created directly through the OneDrive GUI and is also being Shared with the same experimental user using the same permissions given to my Previous Visual Studio Folder.

Both these folders have received the **can edit permissions**. However this folder *IS* showing up in his “Shared With Me” section.

Has any one ran into this issue before? I have spent hours researching this and have not ended up with a conclusive answer.